# How to keep state of user control through post back in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, telerik

How to keep state of user control through post back in asp.net?
I have a user control that it is contain a radTreeView , a dropDownList and a chart and a Button for search. In page_load I fill DropDownList and radTree and Chart. When I load user control to my page.aspx and select a  node of radTreeView or DropDownList and click on Buttn(btnSearch), user control is lost. how to keep state of user control and keep selected node or selected value in dropDownList???

In MyUserControl.ascx

```
<asp:Label ID="lblProductGroup" runat="server" CssClass="h4" Text="products:"></asp:Label>

<telerik:RadTreeView ID="radTreeProduct" runat="server" ShowLineImages="true" Skin="WebBlue">
<WebServiceSettings Path="~/Services/WebService.asmx" Method="GetAllProductList"></WebServiceSettings>
</telerik:RadTreeView>
```

```
   <div class="hundredW">
        <asp:ImageButton ID="imgBtnSearch" runat="server" CssClass="h4"  OnClick="imgBtnSearch_Click" />

                        </div>
<div>
<asp:Chart ID="chartInvoice" runat="server"
                                Palette="BrightPastel" ImageType="Png" BorderDashStyle="Solid" BackSecondaryColor="White"
                                BackGradientStyle="TopBottom" BorderWidth="2" BackColor="#D3DFF0" BorderColor="26, 59, 105"
                                Height="321px" Width="501px">
                                <BorderSkin SkinStyle="Emboss" />
                                <Legends>
                                    <asp:Legend Name="Legend1" BackColor="Transparent" Font="Trebuchet MS, 8.25pt, style=Bold"
                                        IsTextAutoFit="False">
                                    </asp:Legend>
                                </Legends>
                                <Titles>
                                    <asp:Title Alignment="TopCenter" BackColor="180, 165, 191, 228"  BackGradientStyle="TopBottom"
                                        BackHatchStyle="None" Font="Microsoft Sans Serif, 12pt, style=Bold" Name="Title"
                                        ToolTip="Revenue" ForeColor="26, 59, 105">
                                    </asp:Title>

                                </Titles>

                                <ChartAreas>
                                    <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1" BackColor="64, 165, 191, 228" BackSecondaryColor="White"
                                        BorderColor="64, 64, 64, 64" ShadowColor="Transparent" BackGradientStyle="TopBottom">
                                        <AxisY LineColor="64, 64, 64, 64" IsLabelAutoFit="False" ArrowStyle="Triangle">
                                            <LabelStyle Font="Trebuchet MS, 8.25pt, style=Bold" />
                                            <MajorGrid LineColor="64, 64, 64, 64" />
                                        </AxisY>
                                        <AxisX IsLabelAutoFit="False" LineColor="64, 64, 64, 64" ArrowStyle="Triangle"
                                            Interval="1">
                                            <LabelStyle Font="Trebuchet MS, 8.25pt, style=Bold" IsEndLabelVisible="False" Angle="0" />
                                            <MajorGrid LineColor="64, 64, 64, 64" />
                                        </AxisX>

                                    </asp:ChartArea>
                                </ChartAreas>

                            </asp:Chart>
</div>
```

In MyUserControl.ascx.cs

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {

            FillComboBox();//methode for Fill combobox
            CreateRadTreeView();
            CreateChart();
        }
    }
```

.............

In MuPage.aspx.cs

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
               Control ucReport =this.LoadControl("~/UserControl/Repo/MyUserControl.ascx");

ucReport.EnableViewState = true;

                content.Controls.Add(ucReport);

            }
        }
```

Comment: You have added usercontrol dynamically, right?

Comment: yes. In My Page I insert My user control dynamically

Comment: @JayeshGoyani I am edit my question. can ypo help me ?

Comment: You have to add usercontrol all time in page_init.

Answer (score 1):

Load is too late to load dynamic controls, so you'd want to at least load the control in PreInit/Init timeframe.  You have to load it on EVERY postback, not just the initial one.